# How can I order this result set by the named aggregate value?

Tags: sql-server, sum, sql-order-by

I've got this query:

```
Select top 10 PAItemCode, PADescription, Sum(Qty) as 'Qty'
from Invoice
where Unit = 'Sodexo'
group by PADescription, PAItemCode
```

...that does what I want, except that I need the results to be sorted desc based on the vals in the last column (Sum(Qty) as 'Qty')

With this:

```
Select top 10 PAItemCode, PADescription, Sum(Qty) as 'Qty'
from Invoice
where Unit = 'Sodexo'
group by PADescription, PAItemCode
order by Qty
```

...all Qtys are 0 (they are not otherwise). The same is true when I sandwich "Qty" inside single quotes:

```
. . .
order by Qty
```

How can I get this result set to order by the aggregated value descending?

Comment: I would be really careful about using aliases like `'Qty'` - some forms of this are deprecated, and that looks like a string literal in any case. In SQL Server I would prefer the proprietary `[Qty]` *when quoted identifiers are necessary*, but in this case they're not, since `Qty` is not a reserved word or keyword.

Comment: Good to know, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select top 10 PAItemCode, PADescription, Sum(Qty) as 'Qty'
from Invoice
where Unit = 'Sodexo'
group by PADescription, PAItemCode
order by Sum(Qty) desc
```

This should work

Answer (score 4):

You have to also **include SUM(Qty) in order by**, but my opinion is **use with statement / CTE**, it is more readable and also you can apply other logic on grouped data

IF you have use any agreegate function in select statement and you also wants to use that in **GROUP BY** OR **ORDER BY** you must have to apply same logic also.

```
SELECT 
    TOP 10 PAItemCode, 
    PADescription, 
    Sum(ISNULL(Qty,0)) as 'Qty'
FROM Invoice
WHERE Unit = 'Sodexo'
GROUP BY PADescription, PAItemCode
ORDER BY Sum(ISNULL(Qty,0))
```

**Alternate Way use CTE / With statement:**

```
;WITH T AS
(
    SELECT 
        TOP 10 PAItemCode, 
        PADescription, 
        Sum(ISNULL(Qty,0)) as 'Qty'
    FROM Invoice
    GROUP BY PADescription, PAItemCode
    WHERE Unit = 'Sodexo'
)
SELECT 
    T.PAItemCode,
    T.PADescription,
    T.Qty
FROM T  
ORDER BY T.Qty
```

Comment: I would prefer CTE.

Comment: Cougars tracking Elephants?

Comment: I can't getting you @shannon

Comment: What does CTE stand for?

Comment: A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the code is having same name for column used in aggregation and in alias column. Rename the alias column name to something else and order by this new alias name

Answer (score 0):

Thats working on MySQL.
One thing you can try is change the alias name like this:

```
Select PAItemCode, PADescription, Sum(Qty) as 'Qtysum' 
from Invoice 
group by PADescription, PAItemCode 
order by Qtysum desc
```